How to understand the significance of the Waiting and Net I/O thread states of JPA views in JProfiler?
Our team is currently running stress tests and using JProfiler for monitoring.
The target server is a Spring application using Hikari CP with the connection pool size set to 10.
We chose two scenarios for the test: setting concurrent threads to 10 and 40, and then compared the results.
The test results were recorded using Async Sampling for both JPA views and HTTP Server views.
To understand the test results, we referred to the following pages:

The definitive guide to JProfiler (ej-technologies.com)

Finally, JProfiler adds a synthetic "Net I/O" state that keeps track of the times when a thread is waiting for network data. This is important for analyzing servers and database drivers, because that time can be relevant for performance analysis, such as for investigating slow SQL queries.


What is meant by Net IO in JProfiler? - Stack Overflow

A JDBC call that is waiting for the database to return a result is in the net I/O state. In this case, you can see the associated SQL string in the call tree.



And we made the following assumptions:

In JPA views, Waiting thread time is due to the server waiting to get a connection to the database, and Net I/O thread time is the time from when the server starts fetching data from the database until the data is returned.

Based on this and knowing Hikari CP has only 10 connections, we expected that with 40 threads, the waiting thread time would be longer than with 10 threads. This was true, but we also noticed that the Net I/O thread time increased as well, although the increase was small.
If net I/O only includes the time from when data fetching starts until it returns, without including the time waiting for a connection, then theoretically, the time spent should be about the same whether there are 10 or 40 threads. However, our actual tests showed otherwise.
It seems our understanding of Waiting and Net I/O thread states in JPA views might be incorrect, and the official documentation doesn’t provide a clearer explanation.
Can anyone provide a more detailed explanation? Thanks!


If net I/O only includes the time from when data fetching starts until it
returns, without including the time waiting for a connection

That is not the case. Net I/O is determined with instrumentation. JProfiler has a list of methods that perform I/O in the JVM, and it instruments their entry and exit. Inside these calls, there are still CPU operations being performed which will take longer under scheduling pressure.

At what level is the list of methods likely to be intercepted? Is >there any official documentation on this? I understand that >instrumentation is applied at the entry and exit points of methods. >However, regarding JPA views, where does the calculation start and end? >What other times might be included (for example, the time to convert JPQL, HQL)?

There is no documented list of these methods as of 14.0. We try to include as little runnable state as possible, but totally excluding it is often not technically feasable.

What do the terms "CPU operation" and "scheduling pressure" mentioned
here mean? Does it refer to "processes being subject to time slicing,
needing to wait for CPU allocation" and the waiting time and pressure
incurred during "context switches"?

Yes, that's what I was referring to.

Does the whole statement mean that Net I/O includes CPU time, so when
CPU usage increases, even though data retrieval itself doesn't take
much time, the Net I/O time will still be affected and become longer?

Yes, that is the case. The effect should not be significant, though.

So, if the data fetch time is actually low (as observed from Cloud SQL
Inspect and JDBC views in JProfiler), but the Net I/O time increases
with more threads, does that mean it's also affected by CPU usage?

Yes, indeed.

"JProfiler has a list of methods that perform I/O in the JVM" - At what level is the list of methods likely to be intercepted? Is there any official documentation on this? I understand that instrumentation is applied at the entry and exit points of methods. However, regarding JPA views, where does the calculation start and end? What other times might be included (for example, the time to convert JPQL, HQL)?

"there are still CPU operations being performed which will take longer under scheduling pressure" - What do the terms "CPU operation" and "scheduling pressure" mentioned here mean? Does it refer to "processes being subject to time slicing, needing to wait for CPU allocation" and the waiting time and pressure incurred during "context switches"?

Does the whole statement mean that Net I/O includes CPU time, so when CPU usage increases, even though data retrieval itself doesn't take much time, the Net I/O time will still be affected and become longer?

So, if the data fetch time is actually low (as observed from Cloud SQL Inspect and JDBC views in JProfiler), but the Net I/O time increases with more threads, does that mean it's also affected by CPU usage?
